# How to access Ubuntu server 12.10 via hostname,

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I had it working, but then installed LAMP and a few other things to set up a webserver, now PUTTY only allows connection via IP, which works, and Webmin worked with hostname as well, until now... I checked the hostname on the server

```
# hostname
```

This returned the correct name that I gave it in the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.34    dlna2
```

Also, now that the MySql and PHPadmin are installed, along with Apache2, how do I make webpages, then get it online  ?  Do I use DynDNS ?

Mike\

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For remote machines to be able to access your Ubuntu machine by name, those remote machines have to be able to look up the name in question in DNS. The DNS nameserver is generally not the Ubuntu machine but some other machine, e.g., your home modem-router-DHCP-DNS-server. Investigate how the latter is configured.

Comment: hmmmm Ok, will do, but remember, it DID indeed work by name before I installed LAMP, Apache2, etc....